# Adding dates incorrectly

Tags: php, date

Hi I'm not sure how get this equation correct because I not sure about the dates. I know it returns the same date but I'm trying to learn different formats and how to add dates different days. I know may not be the best way of writing the code I still would like to know how to write this code. The equation is :

```
$mhYr + ($vSDday -1day)
My code:

$date = "2015-11-02";
$vStartDate = strtotime($date);
$currentdate = $vStartDate;

$vSDday = date('d',  $currentdate); //day
$monthY = date('m',  $currentdate); //Month
$mhYr = date("01-$monthY"); //first day of any month
```

But I keep getting errors because of the dates.

An example would be 1stOfMonth + (daysOfStartDate -1 day). So if I started on the 2 November i want to perform : 1st Nov + (2 - 1day). But I don't know how to put all together.

Comment: You should check out the `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes, that would make all this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

```
$date = "2015-11-02";
$vStartDate = strtotime($date);
```

and try to print it (  *`echo $vStartDate`*), it will print number of *seconds* difference between 1 january 1970 at midnight and *2015-11-02* , to convert the time to human readable format you need *`getdate($vStartDate )`*, it will return collection format.

```
$date = "2015-11-02";
$vStartDate = strtotime($date);
$timeCollection= getDate($vStartDate);
```

Then you can start doing :

```
$day = $timeCollection["mday"]; //day
$month = $timeCollection["mon"]; // month
$year = $timeCollection["year"]; // year
$hour = $timeCollection["hours"]; // hours
$minute = $timeCollection["minutes"]; // minutes
$seconds = $timeCollection["seconds"]; // seconds
```